# More than 100 search results with Jtwitter

Tags: java, search, jtwitter

I have a function that does the following:

```java
List<Status> list = new ArrayList<Status>();
Twitter twitter = new Twitter();
int num = 300;        
ICallback call = new ICallback() {

    public boolean process(List<Status> statuses) {
        return false;
    }
};
list = twitter.search(hashTag, call, num);
```

I'm trying to retrieve 300 results, but instead I get 100. The return value of the `ICallback` makes no difference.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I looked at the [source](https://github.com/winterstein/JTwitter/blob/master/src/winterwell/jtwitter/Twitter.java) and it looks like the there is a maxResults field that defaults to 100 that restricts the number of results. Just try setting it to 300 or more for your scenario.

Try

```
twitter.setMaxResults(500);
list = twitter.search(hashTag, call, num);
```

Answer (score 2):

The twitter search API documentation says

```
rpp optional - paramter
```

The number of tweets to return per page, up to a max of 100.

per page max results is 100.

```
page optional - parameter
```

The page number (starting at 1) to return, up to a max of roughly 1500 results (based on rpp * page).

Have a look at [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) for more details

Answer (score 1):

check this:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

rpp: 
The number of tweets to return per page, up to a max of 100.
Example Values: 100

In jTwitter api, search method the third parameter is the rpp! So up to 100!

To solve that set the MaxResults! however I also remember that I was using jtwitter for search like that but the API had some bugs about pagination in more the 100 tweets! anyways it is worth you give a try setting the maxResults! otherwise try using twitter4j which I think it is a better api for Java and Twitter